# shell script creates empty zip via crontab, works manually

Tags: bash, macos, cron

I'm trying to schedule the following script to run daily via crontab to back up my notes folder:

```
#!/bin/bash

date=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
backupDir="/Users/MYNAME/backups"

if [ -e "$backupDir/$date.zip" ]
then
    rm -rf "$backupDir/$date.zip"
fi

zip -r "$backupDir/$date.zip" "/Users/MYNAME/Documents/notes/"
```

When I run the script manually via

```
./script.sh
```

it works and creates a ZIP file several MBs large as expected in the correct location. However when I schedule it via cron:

```
00 14 * * * /Users/MYNAME/bin/script.sh
```

It creates a zip 208 bytes large in the correct location which contains nested empty folders to my notes folder e.g. an empty `/Users/MYNAME/Documents/notes/`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try redirecting stderr of the script to a file so you see the error messages.

Comment: I recommend creating a variable to hold `$backupDir/$date.zip` so you don't have to keep repeating that.

Comment: @Barmar I redirected the stdout and stderr to a file. Manually running it shows `adding: path/to/file` hundreds of times for all files being compressed. When scheduled via cron the only file that prints is `adding: Users/MYNAME/Documents/notes/ (stored 0%)`. That makes it seem almost like cron can't see the files in the directory.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue by giving cron Full Disk Access. For steps see this article: https://osxdaily.com/2020/04/27/fix-cron-permissions-macos-full-disk-access/

Comment: Another solution might be to use a LaunchDaemon instead of cron.

Comment: That's what I tried using initially because I read that cron was deprecated in favor of LaunchDaemon. I spent several hours trying to work through various issues until I gave up, frustrated, and then got everything working in ~15 minutes using cron.